# How to find who uses Ctrl-Alt-Back combination?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

In Jetbrains IDEs like `PyCharm`, key combination of `Ctrl-Alt-Back` is used to navigate to previous location in code (like web browser history).

[image]

Unfortunately, under `Ubuntu` this combination does not work. How to know, who holds it?

Comment: ...back or ...left? You use both, which are you interested in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> is set by default to Switch to Workspace Left.

You can change it in:

System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Navigation >> Switch to Workspace Left.

To free <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>, click the setting then type the new accelerator combination that you want to replace it with.

[image]

(Note: You typed Ctrl+Alt+Back but the image from your program shows Ctrl+Alt+Left)